# How can I have nginx serve WordPress at /blog?

Tags: directory, nginx

How can WordPress be made to live at `/blog`, while another application handles the root directory `/`, using nginx?

I have [the ordinary subdomain setup](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress) right now, which works fine.

I've read https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx and changed my config according to [serving WordPress as a subdirectory](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress#Non-root_try_files_to_URL_redirect). In `wp-config.php` I have

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com/blog');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com/blog');
```

but I keep getting 404 errors, or WordPress not loading CSS files. I've also tried

```
location /blog {
  try_files /var/www/wordpress/$uri /var/www/wordpress/$uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

404s again.

This must be an FAQ, but I haven't nailed the search terms for it (`/blog` being so common doesn't help).

Where can I find a full nginx config file and `wp-config` settings that have WordPress live at `/blog`? Do I need to alter any WP settings in its MySQL database?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what *mostly* works:

1. Have an nginx config file for the [subdomain setup](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress), and ensure that http://wordpress.example.com works.
2. In the nginx default config, have a `location` block for `/blog` that proxies to the subdomain:

   ```
   location /blog {
       rewrite ^/blog(/?.*)$ $1 break;  # remove "/blog"
       proxy_set_header Host wordpress.example.com;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_pass http://wordpress.example.com;
   }
   ```
3. In `wp-config.php`, have:

   ```
   define('WP_HOME','http://idorecall.com/blig');
   define('WP_SITEURL','http://idorecall.com/blig');
   ```

I'm saying this "mostly" works because:

- Some page elements may not be loading. For example, the icomoon icons used by the Avada theme in the footer don't show up.
- If you access your /blog URL via https, e.g. at `http://example.com/blog`, but the wordpress subdomain config uses http, browsers will refuse to load many resources, with a "Mixed Content" warning. One solution is to enable HTTPS on the subdomain too (StartSSL has a certificate with one free subdomain). Another, I suspect, is that you'll have to run a [Wordpress database search and replace](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) of http://wordpress.example.com with http://example.com/blog.
- There's an extra request involved with proxy_passing.